# Cannot include CSS or JS in Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I am using the chrome.webRequest API with the onBeforeRequest event. In the callback, I am returning with a redirectUrl value of a local extension document (address obtained with the chrome.extension.getURL function and using the web_accessible_resources property in the manifest file).

However, the document I am loading that is local with the extension has the chrome-extension:// protocol and for some reason both external CSS and JavaScript cannot be loaded. I get given an error about  when trying to include external CSS or JS.

```
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="test.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
```

This is in the head section.

Inline JavaScript is not allowed anymore and overriding that is either troublesome or since impossible on updated GC.

I have tried adding test.css and test.js to the values for web_accessible_resources and even as content scripts.

I can get test.js to execute on websites other than my own document.

On my own document, trying to include CSS or JS externally gets me an error.

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<' (apparently to do with  but these issues only arise when I try and include external CSS or JS).

The expected output is external CSS and JS loading in the document.

The actual result is that I get thrown an error about something totally irrelevant and cannot find any information relevant to my problem when searching about it.

What am I doing wrong here? Am I supposed to do different? I don't understand why Google couldn't talk about this issue and a resolution on their docs?

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts

Comment: It's really really unclear what you're doing there and why `<` is involved. Consider adding [MCVE](/help/mcve) to make the question more answerable.